# Get values out of MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xamarin

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms social media app. I am trying to grab posts joined with users so I can display the posters username.

I grab the posts using:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts AS P INNER JOIN users AS U ON U.id = P.user_id WHERE P.user_id=:userid";
$results = DB::query($sql, array(':userid' => $target_id));
```

Using `print_r` displays it out as:

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [id] => *snip*
>               [0] => *snip*
>               [user_id] => *snip*
>               [1] => *snip*
>               [body] => 56565
>               [2] => 56565
>               [data] => 0
>               [3] => 0
>               [timestamp] => 2018-03-22 00:00:00
>               [4] => 2018-03-22 00:00:00
>               [type] => 1
>               [5] => 0
>               [comments] => 0
>               [6] => 0
>               [users] => 
>               [7] => 
>               [8] => *snip*
>               [username] => username_test
>               [9] => username_test
>               [password] => *snip*
>               [10] => *snip*
>               [user_password] => 
>               [11] => 
>               [email] => *snip*
>               [12] => *snip*
>               [name] => Joe
>               [13] => Joe
>               [bio] => Hello World Test Print
>               [14] => Hello World Test Print
>               [birthday] => 2001-05-30 00:00:00
>               [15] => 2001-05-30 00:00:00
>               [gender] => 0
>               [16] => 0
>               [created] => 2018-03-25 20:29:44
>               [17] => 2018-03-25 20:29:44))

I use to loop through the results using something like below before I added the join:

```
foreach($results as $p) { 
    $username = $p[username']
}
```

But now I don't understand how to get something from users or posts for example If i needed to get the user id how can I specify "id" from users and not "id" from posts and accidentally get the post id.

I tried something like $p[users => username] but that didn't work

Comment: As I understood you need alias In your sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
INNER JOIN users
ON users.id = posts.user_id
WHERE posts.user_id=:userid
```

Your foreach statement is missing quotation marks and closing semicolon:

```
foreach($results as $p) { 
    $username = $p['username'];
}
```

To get the unambiguous ID's:

```
SELECT *, users.id AS uid, posts.id AS postId
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user_id
WHERE posts.user_id=:userid
```

To get the count of likes in the same query:

```
SELECT *, users.id AS uid, posts.id AS postId,
COUNT(L.likes) AS likeCount 
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user_id
LEFT JOIN like AS L ON L.post_id = P.id
WHERE posts.user_id=:userid
```

Comment: I know how to do that but what if for example I need the "id" $p['id'] might return either the id from the posts table or the id from the users table, how would I specify which table?

Comment: Then do this in the query: Select *, users.id AS uid, posts.id AS postId FROM posts
INNER JOIN users
ON users.id = posts.user_id
WHERE posts.user_id=:userid

Comment: Ah thanks! Also lets say I wanted to also count the posts' likes and added `LEFT JOIN like AS L ON L.post_id = P.id` how would I assign the Count of likes to a variable

Comment: Amended the answer to reflect this: assuming that the column name is 'likes'

Comment: Perfect! I accepted the answer but if you don't mind one last thing how do I check if the one who requested the posts ($userid) has liked each post?

Comment: I don't know the DB schema so it's very difficult to answer that

Comment: Could you help point me in the right direction? What would it look like maybe?

Comment: Does Likes have a users_id column, if not there's no way to do that, if yes then LEFT or INNER JOIN on the like.users_id = users.id and a COUNT(*) on that...

Comment: The likes table has user_id|post_id but I don't get how to check if $user_id liked the post since COUNT would count it not check if the requester liked it?

Comment: The INNER or LEFT JOIN will tell you... (ignore the count its irrelevant)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work for you but since you are only interested in userId, why don't you just select what you want?
Then the $result array will only have one entry per recordset.

```
$sql = "SELECT p.user_id FROM posts AS P INNER JOIN users...
```